# programatically downloaded MP3 file is not appearing in any music player

Tags: android, storage, android-music-player

I want downloaded file to appear in Music Players, It is playable when I open it manually from files explorer.
I tried adding Album name and Artist name but it doesn't seem to work.

```
Context context;
public DownloadMusic(Context context)
{
    this.context = context;
}

NotificationCompat.Builder noti;
Notification notify;
NotificationManager manager;
String channel="chennel";
MediaScannerConnection scanner;
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
    try {
        downloadStartNotification(strings[3]);
        URL url = new URL(strings[strings.length-2]);
        URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
        connection.connect();
        int fileLength = connection.getContentLength();
        int progress;
        InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
        File path = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator
                + "G-Music");
        String filepath = path+File.separator+strings[3]+".mp3";
        try {
            path.mkdir();
        }catch (Exception e){}
        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(filepath);
        byte data[] = new byte[1024];
        long total = 0;
        int count;
        showNotification(strings[3]);
        while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
            total += count;
            progress = (int) (total * 100 / fileLength);
            noti.setProgress(100,progress,false);
            noti.setContentText(progress+" %");
            manager.notify(2,noti.build());
            output.write(data, 0, count);
        }
        output.flush();
        output.close();
        input.close();

        modify(filepath,strings);
        downloadFinishNotification(strings[3]);
        musicAdd(filepath);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
void musicAdd(final String path)
{
    File audioFilePath = new File(path);
    context.sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.fromFile(audioFilePath)));
    MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(
            context,
            new String[]{ path },
            new String[]{ "audio/mp3", "*/*" },
            new MediaScannerConnection.MediaScannerConnectionClient()
            {
                public void onMediaScannerConnected()
                {
                }
                public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri)
                {
                }
            });
}
```

I want downloaded file to appear in Music Players, It is playable when I open it manually from files explorer.
I tried adding Album name and Artist name but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to tell the Android system that you have downloaded a new file

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.fromFile(audioFilePath)));
```

**OR** if it's still doesn't work

```
MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(
    context, 
    new String[]{ pathFile1, pathFile2 }, 
    new String[]{ "audio/mp3", "*/*" }, 
    new MediaScannerConnectionClient()
    {
        public void onMediaScannerConnected()
        {
        }
        public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri)
        {
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you for the help sir, but this doesn't seem to work, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @GaganSroay post your latest code implementation in the question.

Comment: @GaganSroay What path you are using?? try with absolute path

Comment: I also tried passing absolute path, still doesn't work

Comment: I checked, file is present in folder and is playable when opened.

Comment: what is the path ?

Comment: /storage/emulated/0/G-Music/Adele - Hello.mp3

Comment: try encoding path because it contains space characters

Comment: @GaganSroay musicAdd(filepath.replaceAll("%20"," "));